# How to arrange comma separated string in Arrays of String in c?

Tags: c, string, matrix

I'm writing a `C` program which will parse comma separated string in Arrays of String.

I have already tried a source code which prints the comma separated string. But I want those strings to be stored in an array of string. The following code uses `strcspn` and uses this following line

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int)field_len, s);
```

to print the strings which I am not able to understand. How can I transfer the printed string in the arrays of string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char ArrayOfString[10][5];

void vSeparateSringByComma(char* string)
  {
    const char delims[] = ",";
    const char *s = string;
    int i = 0, j;
    do 
      {
        size_t field_len = strcspn(s, delims);
        printf("%.*s\n", (int)field_len, s);
        s += field_len;
        i++;
      } 

    while (*s++);   
   }

int main() {
    char string[] = "$,0,3,307,183,18,5,119,1,#";
    vSeparateSringByComma(string);
}
```

The output i am getting is

```
$
0
3
307
183
18
5
119
1
#
```

(after every string there is a newline)
which is perfectly fine. My problem is to transfer these strings to my array of strings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues to work through to convert your function from simply printing the separated strings to `stdout` to saving the separated strings in `ArrayOfString`. Before getting to the changes, let's avoid using *magic numbers* in your code.

```
char ArrayOfString[10][5];
```

In `ArrayOfString` above, `10` and `5` are *magic numbers*. They are hardcoded values that will govern everything from the declaration size to required validation checks to protect your array bounds. Instead of hardcoding values, if you need a constant, define one (or more), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 10
#define COL  5

char ArrayOfString[ROW][COL];
```

Now on to separating your string into *tokens*. The C-library provides a function specifically tailored to separating delimited strings into tokens. Conveniently named [`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html). The only caveat to know about `strtok` is that it modifies the string, so if you need to preserve the original, make a copy first.

To use `strtok (string, delims)` to separate `string` into tokens at `delims`, your first call to `strtok` takes `string` as the 1st parameter. All subsequent calls use `NULL` in its place. You can either make an initial call to `strtok` and then use a while loop to complete the process, or a `for` loop is tailor made for handling the initial call, as well as all subsequent calls with `NULL`.

For example your function utilizing `strtok` to separate `string` into tokens and providing a `size_t` return of the number of tokens copied to `ArrayOfString` could be similar to:

```
char ArrayOfString[ROW][COL];

size_t vSeparateSringByComma (char* string)
{
    const char *delims = ",\n";
    char *s = string;
    size_t n = 0, len;

    for (s = strtok (s, delims); s && n < ROW; s = strtok (NULL, delims))
        if ((len = strlen (s)) < COL)
            strcpy (ArrayOfString[n++], s);
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: '%s' exceeds COL - 1 chars.\n", s);

    return n;
}
```

(**note:** how your array bounds are protected both by the check with `n < ROW` and each row array bound is protected with `(len = strlen (s)) < COL` before the copy to `ArrayOfString[n++]` is made)

(**also note:** how by not using *magic numbers*, if you change the `ROW` or `COL` size in the future, only the constants need changing and the change is automatically incorporated throughout your code by virtue of using constants)

Your example program would then be:

```
int main(void) {

    char string[] = "$,0,3,307,183,18,5,119,1,#";
    size_t n = vSeparateSringByComma (string);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("ArrayOfString[%zu] : '%s'\n", i, ArrayOfString[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrayofstrings
ArrayOfString[0] : '$'
ArrayOfString[1] : '0'
ArrayOfString[2] : '3'
ArrayOfString[3] : '307'
ArrayOfString[4] : '183'
ArrayOfString[5] : '18'
ArrayOfString[6] : '5'
ArrayOfString[7] : '119'
ArrayOfString[8] : '1'
ArrayOfString[9] : '#'
```

**Using `strcspn` and `strspn` Instead of `strtok`**

As discussed in the comments, using `strcspn` to report the number of sequential characters not containing a delimiter allowing you to determined the length of each field. You then need to skip over the delimiters (which in many cases can be made up of more than one delimiter (e.g. `$, 0, 3, ...`).

While `strtok` considers multiple sequential delimiters a single delimiter, you would need a similar way to skip over the intervening delimiters to position your self to read the next field. `strspn` will work nicely using the same `delims`, but this time reporting the number of characters made up of only characters within `delims` (allowing you to add that to your `len` and then `len` to `s` to position yourself for the next read)

A short variation using `strcspn` and `strspn` could be:

```
size_t vSeperateSringByComma (char* string)
{
    const char *delims = ",\n";
    char *s = string;
    size_t n = 0, len;

    while ((len = strcspn (s, delims))) {   /* number of non-delim chars */
        if (len < COL) {                    /* validate it will fit */
            memcpy (ArrayOfString[n], s, len);  /* copy len chars */
            ArrayOfString[n++][len] = 0;    /* nul terminate at len */
        }
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: '%s' exceeds COL - 1 chars.\n", s);

        len += strspn (s + len, delims);    /* scan past delimiter(s) */
        s += len;               /* update s to beginning of next field */
    }

    return n;
}
```

(the output is the same)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: `if ((len = strlen (s)) < COL - 1)` --> `if ((len = strlen (s)) < COL)`?

Comment: Arrgh!, I'm taking my glasses off and just using you -- far more reliable.

Comment: OP's good use of `strcspn()` allows `string` as `const char *` negating the need to allocate temp memory and copy the string.  IMO, better than `strtok()` with its additional thread concerns.

Comment: Agreed, but that becomes a little more esoteric -- do we not suggest standard library functions in lieu of a bit more creative use of different functions to accomplish the same goal, or ... That was my thought process in selecting `strtok`. I do like `strcspn` though. Only drawback would be the multi-delimiter case where you would then need to scan forward past the remaining delimiters -- which `strtok` handles for you.

Comment: To scan forward though delimiters, use `strspn()`.  `strspn()` and `strcspn()` are standard functions.  `strtok()` also destroys `string`, a potential surprise when someone calls `vSeperateSringByComma(string)`.  To prevent that, `strtok()` also then needs `malloc(), strcpy(), free()`.  IMO, `strspn()`.  `strcspn()` makes for cleaner code.

Comment: When i exactly copied and pasted your code and ran it on dev c++ ide, It did not work though your explanation helped me to work through the problem by my own. I will post the solution. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sure, let me know, there should be no issues. If you are interested, I'm happy to add a `strcspn/strspn` approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int)field_len, s);
```

with

```
sprintf(ArrayOfString[i],"%.*s\n", (int)field_len, s);
```

then you can print the 4 first elements with

```
for( i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
   printf("%s" , ArrayOfString[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have learned about both the standard functions `strtok()` and `strcspn()` and i am posting both version of the solution.

**Using strtok()**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW  10
#define COL  30

char ArrayOfString[ROW][COL];

size_t vSeperateSringByComma_New(char* string, char *delims)
{
  char *p;
  p = strtok (string,delims);
  int i = 0,j;
  while (p!= NULL)
  {
    strcpy(ArrayOfString[++i], p);
    p = strtok (NULL, delims);
  }
  return i;
}

int main ()
{
  char string[] ="$,0,3,307,183,18,5,119,1,#";
  char delim[] = ",:";
  printf ("String  \"%s\" is split into tokens:\n",string);
  size_t len = vSeperateSringByComma_New (string, delim);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len+1; i++)   {
    printf ("%s\n",ArrayOfString[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Using strcspn()**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW  10
#define COL  30

char ArrayOfString[ROW][COL];

size_t vSeperateSringByComma(char* string, char *delims)
{
    const char *s = string;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        size_t field_len = strcspn(s, delims);
        sprintf(ArrayOfString[++i],"%.*s", (int)field_len, s);
        s += field_len;
    } while (*s++); 
    return i; 
}

int main() {
    char string[] = "$,0,3,307,183,18,5,119,1,#";
    char delims[] = ",";
    printf ("String  \"%s\" is split into tokens:\n",string);
    int len = vSeperateSringByComma(string, delims);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len+1; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n",ArrayOfString[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: `sprintf(ArrayOfString[++i]` should be `sprintf(ArrayOfString[i++]` or your 1st element will be empty `:)` You should also add to `delims = ",\n";` to avoid the newline dangling off your last token.

Answer (score 0):

Use strncpy() to put your values into array. This **char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)** copies up to n characters from the string pointed to, by src to dest.

```
do
{
    size_t field_len = strcspn(str, delims);
    printf("%.*s\n", (int)field_len, str);
    strncpy (ArrayOfString[cnt++], str, (int)field_len);
    str += field_len;
    i++;
} while (*str++);
```